# sharing large amounts of data between Activity and Service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

Ok, I've been researching the best way to solve this problem for some time so let me break down my needs and findings for you.

Needs:

- An Activity [SendMsg] composes a message body which may include attachments of images up to 5MB.
- When the user sends this message, the message must be uploaded to my server
- This upload must happen synchronously in the sense that I block the user from using the app until it has completed or failed
- When complete, the SendMsg Activity is destroyed if the send was successful - otherwise an error dialog is displayed
- The upload and user experience must persist given any phone rotation or home button presses / phone calls etc

The last bullet here turns out to be the hardest.

findings:

I thought about just doing the work in a static AsyncTask but I don't think that works for me - state gets really messy and it seems as though I have no guarantee the OS doesn't kill the thread when the app is in the background.

I decided to go with a Service in which it is created and bound/unbound from the Activity.  The service spawns an AsyncTask, does the work and then signals the Activity according to its result (SUCCEED/FAIL).  This paradigm seems to work fine except for my large messages.  The Service/Activity communication Message communication is not made for marshalling such large payloads.  *NOTE: if it is not clear, when the user hits send, this form data and file must be made available to the Service.  In some cases this is an image taken from the camera which DOES not and CAN not exist on disk for purposes of the app.

Clearly what I want here is some sort of shared memory store where I can save the data from the Activity.  Then the Activity can signal the Service that it can go ahead and upload that data.

Can such a shared area exists in memory?  Can I get the Application object from a Service and store the data there?

The other problem comes about when the upload finishes but no Activity is bound to the Service but I think I may have figured this one out.  Please let me know if the following makes sense:

1. Service finishes upload
2. Service checks to see if an Activity is currently bound
3. If yes, return error Message which Activity handles via its Message queue
4. If no, store the return code in that shared memory area and flag a boolean there as well
5. When a client Activity is created / resumed, it should first always check this boolean to see if the process is already complete.  If so, dispatch a Message it its own handler and handle the code as before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deal with your memory requirement, I would probably use a `Map` of UUID to a holder class that has all of your message details.  Store this `Map` as a member variable in your `Application` subclass, or as a static variable.  **Make sure to clear this out** when your task completes or fails. If you are sure you won't have multiple requests of this type going at the same time, maybe you can just use a single class instead of a Map or list.

Then, you can accomplish your requirements using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), with help from a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html).  I tend to avoid bound Services in Android, because they are difficult to work with due to screen rotation.  Just pass in the identifier from the Map in the Intent that starts the `IntentService`.

In my opinion, the best way to communicate from your Service back to your Activity is to use a `PendingIntent`.  Basically, you start the Service from your Activity, and pass in a `PendingIntent` in the Intent that starts the Service. When your Service has finished its work, or failed, you call `send()` on the PendingIntent.  Then, your Activity will get a callback in its `onActivityResult()` method.

Doing this has several advantages:

- It's trivially thread safe. You get a long running task done in a separate thread in the `IntentService`, and you get notified on the UI thread when it is finished.
- This supports screen rotation! You can rotate your Activity all you want, and you'll still get the callback in `onActivityResult()`.  Conversely, even if you `finish()` your Activity and start a new one before the PendingIntent is sent, it will not be delivered, which is almost always what you want.

I have a [demo application](https://github.com/wsanville/RotationDemo) that shows this approach.  Basically, you have an [Activity](https://github.com/wsanville/RotationDemo/blob/master/src/co/touchlab/rotationdemo/ServiceActivity.java) which stars some work, and blocks the UI with a progress dialog.  This dialog will be shown again if the screen gets rotated.  The work is done in the [Service](https://github.com/wsanville/RotationDemo/blob/master/src/co/touchlab/rotationdemo/WeatherIntentService.java), which sends the `PendingIntent` back to the Activity.

The last part of your job is to ensure that the device does not go to sleep while your upload is running.  Mark Murphy has written a [nice example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/) and [Service implementation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/wakeful/WakefulIntentService.java) that uses a `WakeLock` to ensure work gets done uninterrupted.

Comment: Thanks.  As far as your statement though "Conversely, even if you finish your Activity and start a new one before the PendingIntent is sent, it will not be delivered, which is almost always what you want." -- what if a user has hit the home button and hangs out at the launcher for a while then going back into my app to make sure their message sent.  If my activity never gets that pending intent, won't it be forever blocked on a progress dialog?

Comment: To clarify, that statement means that if you call `finish()` on the Activity, or if the user presses the back button and finishes the Activity, a `PendingIntent` will not be delivered. It will be delivered in all other cases, like the Activity being stopped and started again, the user pressing Home, the screen turning off, etc. It works so much better than the alternatives (like bound services and broadcasts).  I'm assuming your Progress Dialog will block the use of the Back button, so this seems like a good solution to me.

Comment: great!  This seems like it should work well, I'm a little confused how we get those wins for free though.  Isn't a new Activity being created in the case of orientation change?  How can the Service know about the new Activity?  Or is there some kind of invisible Listener pattern happening here?

Comment: Sorry one additional questtion about your use of the Application class.  How can you get an instance of that from a Service?  (I assume you will need one since you suggest the storage of a non-static Map)

Comment: You can call `getApplication()` and typecast the result from your Service.  I'm in the process of answering your previous comment too.

Comment: By default, yes, new instances of your Activity will be created when the screen is rotated. The Service does not know about any instance of your Activity, it doesn't have to.  Instead, it has the `PendingIntent`, which OS maintains (see them with `adb shell dumpsys activity intents`). The OS maintains the creator of the `PendingIntent`, and I assume that part of a config change (like screen rotation) is to re-associate the `PendingIntent` with the new instance. I'll admit that last part I'm a bit fuzzy about.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should also switch your service to a foreground service that you trigger with a `startService()` call (as opposed to binding to the service). This will ensure the service is kept alive as long as possible. Binding to a service will stop the service once your Activity has been finished (which may happen when the user leaves your app).

I would also take advantage of the notification used with foreground services to let the user know the status of their upload.

To pass information back to your Activity from a service, you may look into a ResultReceiver class. Specifically, look into the DetachableResultReceiver paradigm that Google implemented in one of their IO applications.

Since you have large memory requirements in addition to the communication requirements, you may just want to create a singleton object to share data and state between your activity and service.

Comment: Looks like DetachableResultReceiver would just drop a message that it has no receivers for but I suppose I could queue those up and deliver once someone attaches.  My understanding of binding was that the Service would live as long as the process (not the actviity) even if unbound.  Is that not true?

Comment: Services that are started with a bind will be stopped when they are unbound.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with static variables and let your activity set all the values to that classs. Then start an IntentService and let that service look into the above class. Once the IntentService has processed the message, it will broadcast the message and if there are any activities waiting for a broadcast, they will receive the message.